# Using a function on a numpy linspace in python

Tags: python

My task at university is to model the collision of two particles. One subtask is to calculate the minimal distance of the two particles in dependance of a constant b.

I have to vary the constants b and I wanted to do so by just applying the function below on the whole linspace. However, instead of an array of solutions, the function returns just one value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#given constants
sigma = 1
eps = 0.5
n_b = 100
b_var = np.linspace(0,3,n_b)

E = 0.2

def U(r):
    return 4*eps*((sigma/r)**12 - (sigma/r)**6)

def r_min(b):

    F = lambda r: E*(1 - (b**2/r**2)) - U(r)
    return fsolve(F,1)[0]

print(r_min(b_var))
>>> 0.98549755197
```

Comment: Function `r_min(b)` returns only one index of the array `return fsolve(F,1)[0]` how do you expect it to return an array?

Comment: It is the same without the "[0]" just that the result comes as [0.98549755197].

Comment: if I have understood well you want all the roots of a two dimensional function with respect to one of the dimensions. In that case `fsolve` does not do the job. Take a look at here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088115/finding-the-roots-of-a-large-number-of-functions-with-one-variable